# for $k>1$, calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^k/k^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

I cannot figure out how to show the limit

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{k}}{k^{n}} =0$ where  $k>1$

Using the usual bag of tricks, L'hopitals rule, raising $e$ to some power with $ln$ to simplify it.

If we use L.H.R,

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{k}}{k^{n}} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{kn^{k-1}}{log(n)k^{n}} = \frac{k}{log(k)}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{k-1}}{k^{n}}$

Which doesn't really get us anywhere.

However maybe you can argue that you do this so many times eventually you get $\frac{n^{k-c}}{k^{n}}$ such that $c>k$ and then we get

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{k'}k^{n}}$ where $k' = k-c$

And this limit will approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$ but a rigorous explantation is appreciated.

Comment: Apply L'hospital's rule $k$ times. You get the limit of some constant over $k^n$. Of which it is very easy to show rigorously that it is $0$. You can only apply the rule $k$ times because the numerator and denominator both have to either go to $0$ or infinity. Which isn't the case anymore once the $k$th derivative of the polynomial is constant.

Comment: Steve, your reasoning is right. To write this even more rigorously you can use induction on $k$ (or if $k$ is not an integer, then induction on $\lfloor k \rfloor$). There are more ways to prove this, see e.g. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190610/showing-the-sequence-left-lbrace-fracanna-right-rbrace-for-a-1-dive?noredirect=1 (this is just one duplicate, this question is a very common one).

Comment: $k\in \mathbb{R}$. I don't believe induction can be used?

Comment: Use induction on $\lfloor k \rfloor$. If $\lfloor k \rfloor=0$ then a single application of L'Hopital's rule is enough. If $\lfloor k \rfloor=1$ then two applications are needed, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k^n}$$

Since this is a positive series we can apply the root test:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]\frac{n^k}{k^n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^k}k=\frac1k<1$$

Thus our series converges, and thus $\;\frac{n^k}{k^n}\xrightarrow[n\to
\infty]{}0\;$ ...

Comment: This is the same answer as in the duplicate which I've linked to above.

Comment: @Snaw I Wouldn't be surprised: along the years I've posted very similar answers. Yet in the link you posted I can't see anything related to series...

Comment: Oh, now I saw it. Fred's answer is similar to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1k\left(1+\frac1n\right)^k=\frac1k<1,
$$
the sequence converges to $0$ by the [ratio test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138836/proof-attempt-to-the-ratio-test-for-sequences).